# Neural Network has accuracy of 75% but has bad predictions

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm building a convolutional neural networtk in order to predict 5 emotions from a data set of faces.
After working in the construction of the weights I could get an accuracy of 75%

```
score = model_2_emotion.evaluate(test_datagen.flow(X_test, Y_test, batch_size = 4))
print('Accuracy: {}'.format(score[1]))
```

```
308/308 [==============================] - 17s 56ms/step - loss: 0.6139 - accuracy: 0.7575
Accuracy: 0.7575264573097229
```

But `model_2_emotion.predict(X_test)` returns me this array

```
array([[0.6594997 , 0.00083318, 0.19473663, 0.08065161, 0.06427888],
       [0.6610887 , 0.0008383 , 0.19332188, 0.08035047, 0.06440066],
       [0.66172844, 0.00082645, 0.19264877, 0.08032911, 0.06446711],
       ...,
       [0.66067713, 0.00084266, 0.19318439, 0.08052441, 0.06477145],
       [0.66050553, 0.00085838, 0.19319515, 0.08056776, 0.06487323],
       [0.6602842 , 0.00084602, 0.19372217, 0.08054546, 0.06460217]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Where we can see it's just predecting "correcty" the first emotion (the first column) with the accuracy of 60% and from this array produces me this heat map:

[Heat map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT8E0.png)

Which I think there is something wrong since its passing through the first emotion. Since I got 75% of accuracy but bad predictions, someone knows what's going on?

Comment: My guess is that 75.75..% of your test labels is that first emotion

Comment: 75% training accuracy says effectively nothing about test or validation set performance.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, my accuracy I got it from my testing sets of images, not from training.

Comment: Your question title says 75% accuracy, and this is training accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your confusion matrix (this is not called a heat map), seems like your model is only predicting a single class, and that your data is unbalanced.
How many samples you have for each class (is it unbalanced)?
How many epochs is your model training?
how many neurons your neural network have in the last layer (it is supposed to have 5 neurons) ?

Only looking closer to the data/problem (and in the train/test accuracy curve over epochs) a better suggestion could be made, but your problem seems to be Under/Overfiting, and that you can benefit of better theoretical basis.

Take a look on any source about bias-variance trade off.

https://quantdare.com/mitigating-overfitting-neural-networks/

here are some generic tips: get more data, improve pre processing, improve model (more layers, different kernel sizes, skip connections, batch normalization, different optimization/learning rates etc ...).

Comment: This is totally wrong, you cannot evaluate overfitting or underfitting since there is no validation results in the question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy 
 75% train accuracy, 60% validation/test ...

Comment: Read my comment again, and also overfitting is evaluated with loss, not with accuracy. A validation set has to be used for overfitting detection, not a test set.

Comment: since he is not using cross validation, calling it test or validation set doesn't change the fact that it is new data to the model, and it serves to the exactly same purpose (measure the generalization).

Comment: As @GuintherKovalski my data in unbalanced. Actually I have more data for the third emotion but it is not a big difference among the others. I have about 24,000 images from which third emotion are like 8,000. And in order to get my 75% of accuracy I used ImageDataGenerator to create aumentation images, one for the train, another for validation and other for testing.

Comment: I'm following a course in Udemy and I follow it in each step but I got another weights and is the only difference so I don't know what's happening.

Comment: @yeipi You cannot augment validation and testing data! That results in leaking! This is a major mistake.

Comment: So that is why I don't get the results @Dr.Snoopy? For the 75% of accuracy I used val_datagen to augment validate data because before that I was getting about 20% of accuracy

Comment: Leaking gives you an unrealistic evaluation, and changing the validation set to get better results is scientific misconduct.

Comment: So how can I get a better accuracy without aumenting validation data?